# How do I set up autofill form data to work on a users browser when they come to my site?

Tags: forms, google-chrome, autofill

Keep in mind, I'm not looking to "turn on" autofill on my browser, but rather, I'm working on behalf a web property that wants to implement this feature so their customers can have form data autofilled.

It seems that I can only find browser specific info for how to turn it on, but not how to set it up. I have browser autofill turned on right now, and it works for other sites, but not ours. So, how do I get it to work on our site?

Comment: It's not something you indicate support for. Is your login form using unique name attributes on the input tags with a form tag wrapping them?

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to excuse my lack of knowledge as I'm not a developer. If I look at the source code how do I determine "unique name attributes" or "form tags"? I found this  class="input-form"